# Есть ли в русском языке слова "авторисса" и "архитектрисса"?

Tags: орфография

Правильно ли сказать — авторисса и архитектрисса, когда идет речь о женщинах в професии?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, таких слов в общелитературном русском языке нет. Можно использовать только окказионально, иронически, с оттенком пренебрежительности.

Вообще специальных слов для обозначения половой принадлежности работников разных профессий в русском почти нет. Исключения составляют несколько профессий, где женщины составляли абсолютное большинство (ткачиха, учительница) и некоторые - в том числе подчеркнуто просторечные - варианты для мужских названий типично женских профессий (стюард, балерун, медбрат). Во всех остальных случаях даже просторечной альтернативы не существует.

Comment: Вообще-то "стюард" первично.

Comment: @Morkovkin Ну да. Стюардесса в языках-источниках - производное. Но во-первых, в русском трудно сказать, что первично, а во-вторых, какая разница? Я говорил, что это однн из немногих случаев, когда есть реальная пара для мужского и женского варианта представителя профессии, а уж как эта пара образовалась, никак здесь не использовал  и не интересовался в связи с вопросом.